# PHP で作ったWebページを表示しようとしてもNot Foundになる

Tags: php

> MAMPまたはXAMPPをインストールした場合、以下のディレクトリに「phpinfo.php」を作成します。
>
> MAMPの場合 アプリケーション＞MAMP＞htdocs XAMPPの場合 アプリケーション＞XAMPP＞htdocs
>
> 「phpinfo.php」は、以下の内容をコピーしてください。
>
> `<? phpphpinfo(); ?>`
>
> 正常にWebページが表示されたら、PHPは動作しています。

とあるのですがどうやってWebページを表示するのですか

なにをどうやってもPHPのコードがそのまま表示されます

環境は Mac です。

#### 追記

```
<table border="1">
<tr><th>名前</th><th>価格</th></tr>
<?php
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=men", "root");
  $st = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM udon");
  while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
    $price = htmlspecialchars($row['price']);
    echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$price 円</td></tr>";
  }
?>
</table>
```

を udon_list.php で保存して ブラウザを立ち上げると

```
<table border="1">
    <tr><th>名前</th><th>価格</th></tr>
    <?php
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=men", "root");
    $st = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM udon");
    while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
        $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
        $price = htmlspecialchars($row['price']);
        echo "<tr><td>$name</td><td>$price 円</td></tr>";
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

が 表示 されます

Apache を起動してるのに

../php/でアクセスすると

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

です

Comment: URL http://127.0.0.1:8080/phpinfo.php を 開くと表示されると思います。

Comment: おそらくudon_list.phpをブラウザにドラッグ＆ドロップしているからだと思います。yyzさんが指摘されているようにブラウザのURLを指定して開いてみてください。